# Why am I getting Exception on KieSession reload?

Tags: java, persistence, drools

I'm running a simple test where the KieSession is operating in STREAM mode.  I define "MyEvent" as an event and specify that it should expire in 3s.  After inserting the event, I dispose of the KieSession, sleep for 5s (to allow the timer to expire), and then attempt to reload the session.  However, when I attempt the session reload, I get Exceptions similar to those shown below.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

**kmodule.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="rules" eventProcessingMode="stream" packages="rules">
        <ksession name="ksession-rules"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

**MyEvent.drl**:

```
package com.mytest.stream;

import java.util.Date;

declare MyEvent
    @role( event )
    @expires( 3s ) 
end

rule 'MyEvent'
when
    $m: MyEvent()
then
    System.out.println(new Date() + " demoReload: Got MyEvent, id=" + $m.getId());
end
```

**MyEvent.java**:

```
package com.mytest.stream;
import java.io.Serializable;
public class MyEvent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String id;
    public MyEvent(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml**:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource</jta-data-source>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.BTMTransactionManagerLookup" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**DroolsTest.java**:

```
package com.mytest.stream;

import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.kie.api.KieBase;
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.Environment;
import org.kie.api.runtime.EnvironmentName;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

import bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices;
import bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource;

import com.mytest.stream.MyEvent;

import java.util.Date;
public class DroolsTest {

    @Test
    public void demoReloadFailure() throws Throwable {    
        System.getProperties().put("java.naming.factory.initial","bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixInitialContextFactory");
        PoolingDataSource ds = new PoolingDataSource();
        ds.setUniqueName("jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource");
        ds.setClassName("org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource");
        ds.setMaxPoolSize( 3 );
        ds.setAllowLocalTransactions( true );
        ds.getDriverProperties().put( "user", "sa" );
        ds.getDriverProperties().put( "password", "" );
        ds.getDriverProperties().put( "URL", "jdbc:h2:file:./sql/mytest");
        ds.init();

        try {
            KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
            Environment env = ks.newEnvironment();
            env.set( EnvironmentName.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY, Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "myPU" ) );
            env.set( EnvironmentName.TRANSACTION_MANAGER,TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager() );
            KieContainer kieContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
            KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase("rules");
            KieSession kieSession = ks.getStoreServices().newKieSession(kieBase, null, env);   
            long kieSessionId = kieSession.getIdentifier();
            kieSession.insert(new MyEvent("EVENT1"));
            kieSession.fireAllRules();
            kieSession.dispose(); 

            // Timer in MyEvent.drl set for 3 second expiration, so it will already have expired
            // when session reload is attempted.
            //
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            kieSession = ks.getStoreServices().loadKieSession( kieSessionId, kieBase, null, env );
            kieSession.fireAllRules();
            kieSession.dispose();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(new Date() + " demoReloadFailure: Caught Exception, message=" + e.getMessage());
        }
    } 
}
```

**pom.xml**:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mytest.stream</groupId>
  <artifactId>drools-stream</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <properties>
    <drools.version>6.3.0.Final</drools.version>
  </properties>
  <!-- JBOSS repository -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
      <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
      <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-persistence-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${drools.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.14</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>[1.4.186,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.btm</groupId>
      <artifactId>btm</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Persistence using hibernate -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Log (including NullPointerException; some lines omitted to conform to stackoverflow character limit)**:

```
[main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource  - building XA pool for jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource with 0 connection(s)
20   [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.XAPool  - setting vendor property 'URL' to 'jdbc:h2:file:./sql/mytest'
23   [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.XAPool  - setting vendor property 'user' to 'sa'
23   [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.XAPool  - setting vendor property 'password' to ''
35   [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.timer.TaskScheduler  - task scheduler backed by ConcurrentSkipListSet
50   [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.timer.TaskScheduler  - scheduling pool shrinking task on an XAPool of resource jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource with 0 connection(s) (0 still available) for Tue Jan 06 21:47:35 EST 1970
50   [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.timer.TaskScheduler  - removing task by an XAPool of resource jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource with 0 connection(s) (0 still available)
51   [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.timer.TaskScheduler  - scheduled a PoolShrinkingTask scheduled for Tue Jan 06 21:47:35 EST 1970 on an XAPool of resource jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource with 0 connection(s) (0 still available), total task(s) queued: 1
53   [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.Configuration  - loading default configuration
53   [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.Configuration  - no configuration file found, using default settings
129  [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging  - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider
229  [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.ProviderChecker  - Persistence-unit [myPU] requested PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider]
235  [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  - PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: myPU
    persistence provider classname: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    classloader: null
    excludeUnlistedClasses: false
    JTA datasource: jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource
    Non JTA datasource: null
    Transaction type: JTA
    PU root URL: file:/C:/Users/ks922p/workspace_luna/drools-stream-a/target/classes/
    Shared Cache Mode: null
    Validation Mode: null
    Jar files URLs []
    Managed classes names [
        org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo
        org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo]
    Mapping files names []
    Properties [
        hibernate.max_fetch_depth: 3
        hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class: org.hibernate.transaction.BTMTransactionManagerLookup
        hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        hibernate.show_sql: true
        hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update]
245  [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl  - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator].
246  [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl  - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccIntegrator].
248  [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl  - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cache.internal.CollectionCacheInvalidator].
248  [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl  - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator].
8266 [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction  - executing synchronization a DeferredReleaseSynchronization of a JdbcPooledConnection from datasource jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource in state NOT_ACCESSIBLE with usage count 0 wrapping xads1: conn2: url=jdbc:h2:file:./sql/mytest user=SA with status=ROLLEDBACK
8266 [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.DeferredReleaseSynchronization  - DeferredReleaseSynchronization requeuing a JdbcPooledConnection from datasource jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource in state NOT_ACCESSIBLE with usage count 0 wrapping xads1: conn2: url=jdbc:h2:file:./sql/mytest user=SA
8266 [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.AbstractXAStatefulHolder  - notifying 2 stateChangeEventListener(s) about state changing from NOT_ACCESSIBLE to IN_POOL in a JdbcPooledConnection from datasource jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource in state NOT_ACCESSIBLE with usage count 0 wrapping xads1: conn2: url=jdbc:h2:file:./sql/mytest user=SA
8266 [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnection  - closing 0 dangling uncached statement(s)
8266 [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnection  - clearing warnings of conn3: url=jdbc:h2:file:./sql/mytest user=SA
8266 [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.AbstractXAStatefulHolder  - state changing from NOT_ACCESSIBLE to IN_POOL in a JdbcPooledConnection from datasource jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource in state NOT_ACCESSIBLE with usage count 0 wrapping xads1: conn2: url=jdbc:h2:file:./sql/mytest user=SA
8266 [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.AbstractXAStatefulHolder  - notifying 2 stateChangeEventListener(s) about state changed from NOT_ACCESSIBLE to IN_POOL in a JdbcPooledConnection from datasource jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource in state IN_POOL with usage count 0 wrapping xads1: conn2: url=jdbc:h2:file:./sql/mytest user=SA
8266 [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnection  - requeued JDBC connection of a PoolingDataSource containing an XAPool of resource jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource with 2 connection(s) (1 still available)
8266 [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.XAPool  - a connection's state changed to IN_POOL, notifying a thread eventually waiting for a connection
8266 [main] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.DeferredReleaseSynchronization  - DeferredReleaseSynchronization requeued a JdbcPooledConnection from datasource jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource in state IN_POOL with usage count 0 wrapping xads1: conn2: url=jdbc:h2:file:./sql/mytest user=SA
8267 [main] WARN  org.drools.persistence.jta.JtaTransactionManager  - Unable to commit transaction
bitronix.tm.internal.BitronixRollbackException: RuntimeException thrown during beforeCompletion cycle caused transaction rollback
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.commit(BitronixTransaction.java:241)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager.commit(BitronixTransactionManager.java:143)
    at org.drools.persistence.jta.JtaTransactionManager.commit(JtaTransactionManager.java:236)
    at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.<init>(SingleSessionCommandService.java:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.buildCommandService(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:143)
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.loadKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:111)
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.loadKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:39)
    at com.mytest.stream.DroolsTest.demoReloadFailure(DroolsTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ObjectTypeNode$ExpireJobContextTimerOutputMarshaller.serialize(ObjectTypeNode.java:618)
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.ProtobufOutputMarshaller.writeTimers(ProtobufOutputMarshaller.java:882)
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.ProtobufOutputMarshaller.serializeSession(ProtobufOutputMarshaller.java:214)
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.ProtobufOutputMarshaller.writeSession(ProtobufOutputMarshaller.java:120)
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.ProtobufMarshaller.marshall(ProtobufMarshaller.java:154)
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.ProtobufMarshaller.marshall(ProtobufMarshaller.java:138)
    at org.drools.persistence.SessionMarshallingHelper.getSnapshot(SessionMarshallingHelper.java:79)
    at org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo.transform(SessionInfo.java:96)
    at org.drools.persistence.TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.beforeCompletion(TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.java:57)
    at org.drools.persistence.jta.JtaTransactionSynchronizationAdapter.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionSynchronizationAdapter.java:54)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.fireBeforeCompletionEvent(BitronixTransaction.java:532)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.commit(BitronixTransaction.java:235)
    ... 34 more
8268 [main] WARN  org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService  - Could not commit session
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to commit transaction
    at org.drools.persistence.jta.JtaTransactionManager.commit(JtaTransactionManager.java:239)
    at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.<init>(SingleSessionCommandService.java:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.buildCommandService(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:143)
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.loadKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:111)
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.loadKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:39)
    at com.mytest.stream.DroolsTest.demoReloadFailure(DroolsTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: bitronix.tm.internal.BitronixRollbackException: RuntimeException thrown during beforeCompletion cycle caused transaction rollback
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.commit(BitronixTransaction.java:241)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager.commit(BitronixTransactionManager.java:143)
    at org.drools.persistence.jta.JtaTransactionManager.commit(JtaTransactionManager.java:236)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ObjectTypeNode$ExpireJobContextTimerOutputMarshaller.serialize(ObjectTypeNode.java:618)
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.ProtobufOutputMarshaller.writeTimers(ProtobufOutputMarshaller.java:882)
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.ProtobufOutputMarshaller.serializeSession(ProtobufOutputMarshaller.java:214)
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.ProtobufOutputMarshaller.writeSession(ProtobufOutputMarshaller.java:120)
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.ProtobufMarshaller.marshall(ProtobufMarshaller.java:154)
    at org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.ProtobufMarshaller.marshall(ProtobufMarshaller.java:138)
    at org.drools.persistence.SessionMarshallingHelper.getSnapshot(SessionMarshallingHelper.java:79)
    at org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo.transform(SessionInfo.java:96)
    at org.drools.persistence.TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.beforeCompletion(TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.java:57)
    at org.drools.persistence.jta.JtaTransactionSynchronizationAdapter.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionSynchronizationAdapter.java:54)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.fireBeforeCompletionEvent(BitronixTransaction.java:532)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.commit(BitronixTransaction.java:235)
    ... 34 more
Wed Apr 20 16:56:06 EDT 2016 demoReloadFailure: Caught Exception, message=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. You may want to try this in 6.4, and if it is still failing, I would file a bug report.

Comment: @Esteban: thanks for the tip; will give it a try

Comment: @EstebanAliverti Please check my arguments - I can't align "fireAllRules", STREAM and session reload.

Comment: @Esteban: well, I tried Drools 6.4.0.Final, and at first things seemed to work better: was not getting Exceptions on KieSession reload attempt.  I was however, getting a different error.  After successfully reloading the KieSession, I was inserting a new event.   For some strange reason, the rule was firing three times for this single insertion and the count was being reported as three, not one!?  To experiment, I added "no-loop" to the rule, but this didn't help (still getting same error).   Next, I tried adding "lock-on-active".   When I did this, however, the Exceptions started again.

Comment: @Esteban: Should I file a bug report on 6.4.0.Final, or would you like me to first do some more experimenting?

Answer (score 0):

We have a session running in STREAM mode that has been disposed (!) and is then pulled out of the hat again. I think that a session that has been disposed is gone, dead and buried: all resources have been relinquished.

Also, I wonder what you intend with triggering an event processing session that runs with a real time clock with fireAllRules which doesn't allow for timeout expiries in the first place. fireUntilHalt is to be used for event processing.

Also, putting pending timeouts "on ice" raises serious doubts regarding the logical consistency of a Drools application. If a timer expires while the session is hibernating, facts should be retracted and/or rules should fire, which should trigger other facts, and so on. Typically, such actions depend on being done "on time" or "in time", not when the ice thaws.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I'm persisting the session, so even though I do a "dispose", I can retrieve the session with its ID (in fact, the Exceptions seem to be intermittent.   Sometimes I can in fact successfully reload the persisted session).   Also, when I run in CLOUD mode, I can invariably do a "dispose" and then reload the persisted session.

Comment: Was not aware that fireAllRules() is incompatible with timer expiries.  Thanks for the info!  We would like to use the persistence API, and our understanding is the session persistence is not compatible with fireUntilHalt().   Is that correct, or are we mistaken?

Comment: Regarding timers expiring "when the ice thaws", what is the recommended procedure for dealing with timers that are still active when a session crashes (that's what we're trying to simulate with the "dispose" and reload sequence: the crash of a persisted session and its subsequent reload)?  Thanks again for the feedack, laune.

Comment: I'm not aware of any documentation relating persisting and dispose for sessions in STREAM or in CLOUD mode. I can only say that the semantics of a STREAM session using CEP with a real-time clock are highly dubious. I'd also insist on an exact description of what happens to a timer (for a fact expiry and resulting from a timer rule attribute) if fireAllRules terminates and the session is disposed, or not disposed and crashes and is reloaded from the backup.

Comment: (Ctd.) Any expiry happening when the session is not active will happen in a burst and resulting data (possibly events) will have a false (delayed) timestamp. One does not expect Drools to permit the implementation of a real-time *application*, but I think that timeliness of events may still be essential to the correctness of a "soft" real-time application.

Comment: I tried to incorporate your suggestions in some additional testing.   That is, 1) I invoked fireUntilHalt() in a separate thread (versus fireAllRules() in the same thread), and 2) instead of disposing of the KieSession, I forced a NullPointerException to better simulate a real KieSession crash.   However, as we had thought, fireUntilHalt() seems not to be compatible with persistence.  Got following: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Command session.fireUntilHalt(); cannot be issued on a persisted session".  Not sure where to go from here.   Any ideas, laune?

Comment: Real-time and restart from some previous state and "catching up with the past" is dubious. - Let's say that the granularity of your timers is 1s. You can proceed through (almost) real time by running fireAllRules every second, with or without considering the arrival of event immediately. (I'd need to know more of the nature of your app to advise on this, but I guess you can decide that just as well.) The upshoot of this approach should be that your session is always up-to-date. - Now as for restarting after a crash, I have my reservations anyway...

Comment: (ctd.) ... because can you avoid running into the same exception after reload and recovery? Is some user there who'll retry? Do you need to replay inputs that haven't been processed? - Would staged processing of events help with persisting the stable results? If the frontend crashes, it doesn't have any persistent data; the backend isn't real-time any more.

Comment: Per your suggestion, ran fireAllRules(), followed by 1s sleep in separate thread.   Still getting Exceptions on reload attempt.  Difficult in limited space to discuss your questions regarding our motivations for reload of crashed session, but basically trying to build in robustness.  E.g.  If we're tracking memory usage of external entity over time, would be nice to avoid losing Event history if inadvertent reboot occurs.

Comment: (ctd.) Or, as another example, Rule issues Request to external entity and is waiting for Response when inadvertent reboot occurs.  Reload of crashed session would enable Request/Response matching.  Make sense?

Comment: Too late for me today. Will reconsider tomorrow.

Comment: Any further thoughts, laune?

Comment: I think that the incompatibility of fireUntilHalt and persistence ties in nicely with the problem of running into an exception on reload when there was a timer running at crash time. IMHO, @expires and several other add-ons intended to "help" programmers create problems under certain complex circumstances. If you pursue the idea of running once per second, it is easy to manually purge all old events. (Insert a Tick event, retract anything older than n sec - takes one rule.)

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, laune.  Per Esteban Aliverti's suggestion, I'm going to open a bug (as expired timers should not cause Exceptions to be thrown on an attempted reload of a persisted KieSession operating in STREAM mode).

Comment: Thanks for the info.